# How to apply "selected" element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, selectedvalue

I want to make number 90 as default value.
Anyone know how to apply `selected` element like in HTML below into jQuery?

**Example in HTML**

```
<select id="threshold">
    <option value="90" selected>90</option>   /* example selected in HTML */
</select>
```

How to apply `selected` in jQuery whereby number 90 as default value?

```
$("#threshold").append($("<option>",{value: "70",text: "70%"}));
$("#threshold").append($("<option>",{value: "80",text: "80%"}));
$("#threshold").append($("<option>",{value: "90",text: "90%"}));
```

Comment: `selected: true`

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
$("#threshold").append($("<option>",{ value: "90",text: "90%", selected:true }));
```

```js
$("#threshold")
.append($("<option>",{value: "70",text: "70%"}))
.append($("<option>",{value: "80",text: "80%"}))
.append($("<option>",{value: "90",text: "90%", selected:true }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="threshold">
</select>
```

or

```
$("#threshold")
  .append($("<option>",{value: "90",text: "90%"}))
  .val("90");
```

```js
$("#threshold")
.append($("<option>",{value: "70",text: "70%"}))
.append($("<option>",{value: "80",text: "80%"}))
.append($("<option>",{value: "90",text: "90%"}))
.val(90);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="threshold">
</select>
```

shorter:

```js
const curTH = 90;
$.each([70, 80, 90], (_, item) =>
  $("<option>",{ value: item, text: item + "%", "selected": item === curTH ? true : false })
  .appendTo("#threshold")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="threshold">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tell jQuery which one should be selected by adding `selected: true` in the object

```js
const options = [
   {value: "70",text: "70%"}
  ,{value: "80",text: "80%"}
  ,{value: "90",text: "90%", selected: true}
];

$("#threshold").append(options.map(o => $("<option>", o)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="threshold"></select>
```